# How to find a list of player IDs from fbref?

Tags: python

I'm using Python to extract data for Premier League players from the fbref website. (https://fbref.com/en/) I want to find each player's information for each match they've played. The URL format for such pages is "https://fbref.com/en/players/" + player_id + "/matchlogs/" + season + "/summary/" + first_name + "-" + surname + "-Match-Logs". I therefore need each player's name, surname and ID.

Every Premier League player's name and season stats can be found at https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats (the 2nd table). Unfortunately, this contains the player names but not their fbref IDs.

Anyone know how to navigate the website to find this information? Maybe someone has already created a tool for it?